# How would I validate these input fields if I am not using a form group?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-material

here is the HTML for the inputs:
`

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="popStartDate">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef scope="col">Start Date</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let expandElement; let i = index">
                        <span *ngIf="!editAward">
                            {{expandElement.popStartDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
                        </span>
                            <mat-form-field  *ngIf="editAward" class="from-date" >
                                <mat-label>
                                    Start Date
                                </mat-label>
                            <input 
                            placeholder=" {{expandElement.popStartDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}"
                            matInput 
                            (dateChange)="onDateChange($event, row.title, 'start')"
                            [owlDateTime]="fromReport" 
                            [owlDateTimeTrigger]="fromReport" 
                            [min]="setPreviousYearsDate"
                            name="report-from"
                            id="report-from" 
                            [(ngModel)]="expandElement.popStartDate">
                            <span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="fromReport" class="cal-icon">
                                <span class="material-icons">
                                  calendar_today
                                </span>
                            </span>
                            <owl-date-time #fromReport [pickerType]="'calendar'"></owl-date-time>
                        </mat-form-field>

                    </td>               
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="popEndDate">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef scope="col">End Date</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let expandElement">
                    <span  *ngIf="!editAward">
                        {{expandElement.popEndDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
                    </span> 
                        <mat-form-field *ngIf="editAward" class="to-date">
                            <mat-label>
                                End Date
                            </mat-label>
                            <input 
                        placeholder=" {{expandElement.popEndDate | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}"
                        matInput 
                        (dateChange)="onDateChange($event, row.title, 'end')"
                        [owlDateTime]="fromReport" 
                        [owlDateTimeTrigger]="fromReport" 
                        [min]="setPreviousYearsDate"
                        name="fromReport"
                        id="{{ index }} report-from" 
                        [(ngModel)]="expandElement.popEndDate">
                        <span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="fromReport" class="cal-icon">
                            <span class="material-icons">
                              calendar_today
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <owl-date-time 
                        #fromReport
                         [pickerType]="'calendar'" 
                         (dateChange)="onDateChange($event, row.title, 'end')"
                        ></owl-date-time>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <div *ngIf="errMsg" class="err">The start date cannot be later than the current date.</div>
                </td>

            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="amountWithFee">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef scope="col">Award Amount including Fee</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let expandElement">
                    <span *ngIf="!editAward">
                        {{expandElement.amountWithFee | currency:'USD':'symbol'}}
                    </span>
                    <mat-form-field *ngIf="editAward" class="amount">
                        <mat-label>
                            Amount Including Fee
                        </mat-label>
                        <span>
                            <input 
                            [(ngModel)]="expandElement.amountWithFee" 
                            matInput 
                            placeholder=" {{expandElement.amountWithFee | currency:'USD':'symbol'}}" 
                            type="number" 
                            name="" 
                            id="">
                        </span>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
```

`

here is the TS with an implementation:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2021-2030 NITAAC NEOS
 * All rights reserved.
 * This software is the confidential and proprietary information of NITAAC.
 * You shall not disclose such Confidential Information and shall use it only in
 * accordance with the terms of the contract agreement you entered into
 * with NITAAC.
 */
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';

import {DataService} from '../../../gss/services/data.service';
import {UtilService} from '../../services/utils';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {RFQEditAwardPeriodInfoComponent} from '../../modals/rfq-edit-award-period-info-popup/rfq-edit-award-period-info.component';
import {GwacConstants} from '../../../../shared/constants/gwac.contants';
import { SaveSuccessComponent } from '../../../../shared/popup/save-success/save-success.component';
import { GeneralSaveSuccessComponent } from '../../../../shared/popup/general-save-success/general-save-success.component';
import { SaveQuestionPopupComponent } from '../../modals/save-question-popup/save-question-popup.component';
import { ConfirmOptionPeriodDatesComponent } from '../../modals/confirm-option-period-dates/confirm-option-period-dates.component';

const ResponseSuccess = 200;

const Constant = {
    base: 'Base',
    option: 'Option Period'
};

@Component({
    selector: 'rfq-award-administer',
    templateUrl: './rfq-award-administration.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./rfq-award-administration.component.scss'],
    animations: [
        trigger('detailExpand', [
            state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0', display: 'none' })),
            state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
            transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('50ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
        ]),
    ]
})

export class RfqAwardAdministrationComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Output() sendRfqInfo: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SaveSuccessComponent | GeneralSaveSuccessComponent | SaveQuestionPopupComponent>;
    checkDatesDialog: MatDialogRef<ConfirmOptionPeriodDatesComponent>;

    companies;
    selectedCH;
    userInfo;
    orderId;
    selectedAwardType;
    chListSubscription: Subscription;
    originalAwardSubscription: Subscription;
    conformedAwardSubscription: Subscription;
    awardTable = new MatTableDataSource();
    conformedAwardTable: any;
    total;
    noAwardTypeSelected = false;
    awardTypes: any[] = [
        { id: 'ORIGINAL', title: 'Original Award' },
        { id: 'MOD', title: 'Modification' },
        { id: 'CONFORMED', title: 'Conformed Award' }
    ];

    awardColumns = ['expand_buttons', 'contractorName', 'orderAuthNumber', 'awardAmount', 'deliveryType', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'totalAwardAmount'];
    expandDisplayColumns = ['nameCode', 'title', 'typeName'];
    expandDisplayColumns1 = ['popTitle', 'popStartDate', 'popEndDate', 'amountWithFee'];
    conformedColumns = ['period', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'ceilingAmount', 'newFunding'];
    // Documents data when an item is expanded, expandTableData => Documents
    expandTableData: any[];
    // Pop data when an item is expanded, expandTableData1 => Periods of Performance
    expandTableData1: any[];
    expandedElement: any;
    pageMode;
    conformedTotalCeilingAmount;
    conformedTotalCurrentlyFundedAmount;
    optionMap;
    deliveryMap;
    noAwardFromCH;
    hideModsPage = false;
    guidanceText: string;
    editAward = false
    popInfoMissing = false;
    amountWithFee: number;
    awardStartDate: any;
    awardEndDate: any;
    currentDate: Date;
    setPreviousYearsDate: Date;
    checkEndDate: number;
    checkStartDate: number;
    startDateEntered: any
    checkAwardDateEntered: number;
    showAwardDateErrMsg = false;
    isBaseDate = false;
    specificRowStartDate: any;
    errMsg = false;
    editAwardInfoComponent: MatDialogRef<RFQEditAwardPeriodInfoComponent>;

    constructor(private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
        private readonly dataService: DataService,
        private readonly router: Router,
        readonly dialog: MatDialog,
        private readonly utilService: UtilService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.createMenuMap();
        this.determineText();
        this.currentDate = new Date()
        this.conformedAwardTable = new MatTableDataSource();
        this.conformedAwardTable.data = [];
        this.chListSubscription = this.dataService.getListOfOrgnization({ orderIdf: this.orderId }).subscribe(data => {
            if (data.status === ResponseSuccess) {
                if (data.object.length > 0) {
                    this.companies = data.object;
                    this.pageMode = 'mod';
                    this.getOriginalAwardByCH();
                } else {
                    this.noAwardFromCH = true;
                }
            }
        });
        sessionStorage.removeItem('checkModZero');
    }

    //check gwacCode to determin guidance text display
    determineText() {
        const gwacCode = sessionStorage.getItem('gwacCode');
        if (GwacConstants.isCIOCS(gwacCode)) {
            this.guidanceText = 'you can add modifications or add shipping details.';
        } else {
            this.guidanceText = 'you can add modifications.';
        }
    }
    createMenuMap() {
        this.optionMap = new Map()
            .set('ORIGINAL', { pageMode: 'original', fun: 'getOriginalAwardByCH' })
            .set('MOD', { pageMode: 'mod' })
            .set('CONFORMED', { pageMode: 'conformed', fun: 'getConformedAwardByCH' });

        this.deliveryMap = new Map()
            .set('POP', 'Period of Performance')
            .set('DATE', 'Delivery Date')
            .set('DAYS_AFTER', 'Delivery Days after Award');
    }

    getOriginalAwardByCH() {
        const request = { orderIdf: this.orderId, organizationIdf: this.selectedCH };
        this.originalAwardSubscription = this.dataService.getOriginalAwards(request).subscribe(res => {
            if (res.status === ResponseSuccess && res.object) {
                this.awardTable.data = res.object.awardResponses;
                this.expandedElement = this.awardTable.data[0];
                this.changeDeliveryType(this.expandedElement);
                this.openDetail(this.expandedElement);                                            
            }
        });
    }

    changeDeliveryType(row) {
        const dType = row.deliveryType;
        row.deliveryType = this.deliveryMap.get(dType);
    }

    // This code is duplicated because it needs the exact same function, which is implemented in another component,
    // but it is too specific function to generalize.
    openDetail(row) {
        this.total = this.sumOriginalAmount(row);

        this.expandTableData = row.awardDocuments;
        if (row.periods && row.periods.length > 0) {
            this.expandTableData1 = [];
            row.periods.forEach(el => {
                this.expandTableData1.push(Object.assign({}, el));
            });
            this.expandTableData1 = this.addTitleToPop(this.expandTableData1);
            // There is column names duplication among multiple tables so column names have to be changed
            this.expandTableData1 = this.utilService.changeKeyNames(this.expandTableData1, [{ old: 'title', new: 'popTitle' },
            { old: 'startDate', new: 'popStartDate' }, { old: 'endDate', new: 'popEndDate' }]);
        } else {
            this.expandTableData1 = [];

        }
    }
    // sum of total original amount
    sumOriginalAmount(row) {
        return row.periods.reduce((acc, el: any) => acc + el.amountWithFee, 0);
    }
    getConformedAwardByCH() {
        const request = { orderIdf: this.orderId, organizationIdf: this.selectedCH };
        this.conformedAwardSubscription = this.dataService.getConformedAwards(request).subscribe(res => {
            if (res.status === ResponseSuccess && res.object) {
                this.conformedAwardTable.data = this.addTitleToPop(res.object);
                this.conformedAwardTable.data = this.utilService.changeKeyNames(this.conformedAwardTable.data, [{ old: 'title', new: 'period' }]);
                this.conformedTotalCeilingAmount = this.sumConformedAmount();
                this.conformedTotalCurrentlyFundedAmount = this.sumCurrentlyFundedAmount();
            }
        });
    }

   onDateChange(evt, el, period){
    
    const tt = new Date(evt.value)
    sessionStorage.setItem('popStartDate', this.conformedAwardTable.data[0].startDate );
    if(this.conformedAwardTable.data.length > 1){
        this.conformedAwardTable.data.forEach((ii, index) =>{
            if((el === ii.title)) {
                if(el !== 'Base'){
                    if(period === 'start'){
                        this.checkOptionPeriodStartDate(this.conformedAwardTable.data[index].endDate);
                        this.checkAwardStartDate(tt, this.conformedAwardTable.data[index -1 ].startDate, el);
                    } else {
                        this.checkAwardEndDate(tt, this.conformedAwardTable.data[index].startDate, el)
                    }
                } else{
                    this.checkBaseStartDate(tt, this.conformedAwardTable.data[index].endDate, el)
                }
            }
        });
    } else if (this.conformedAwardTable.data.length ===1){
        this.checkBaseStartEndDate(tt, this.conformedAwardTable.data, el, period)
    }
    this.checkAllDates(this.conformedAwardTable.data);
   }
    // check base start and end date
    checkBaseStartEndDate(tt, data, el, period) {
        if (period === 'start') {
            this.checkBaseStartDate(tt, data[0].endDate, el);
        } else if (period === 'end') {
            this.checkBaseEndDate(tt, data[0].startDate, el);
        }
    }
   
   checkOptionPeriodStartDate(eachRowStartDate){
    this.specificRowStartDate = new Date(eachRowStartDate).getTime()
   }
   checkAwardStartDate(selectedDate, date, el){
        const checkBaseDate = new Date(sessionStorage.getItem('startDate')).getTime();
        const previousDate = new Date(date).getTime();
        const currentStartDate = new Date(selectedDate).getTime();
        if(currentStartDate > checkBaseDate){
            this.currentStartDateValidation(currentStartDate, previousDate, el);
        }else{
            this.confirmSelectedDates('baseErr', el);
        }
   }

   currentStartDateValidation(startDate,previousDate, el){
        if (startDate <= previousDate){
            this.confirmSelectedDates('errStartDate', el)
        } else if (startDate >= this.specificRowStartDate) {
            this.confirmSelectedDates('startDateLessThanEndDate', el)
        }
   }

   checkAwardEndDate(selectedEndDate, startDate, period){
        const currentStartDate = new Date(startDate).getTime();
        const currentEndDate = new Date(selectedEndDate).getTime();
        if (currentEndDate <= currentStartDate) {
            this.confirmSelectedDates('errEndDate', period);
        }
   }

   checkBaseStartDate(selectedStartDate, endDate, period) {
        const currentStartDate = new Date(selectedStartDate).getTime();
        const currentEndDate = new Date(endDate).getTime();
        if (currentEndDate <= currentStartDate) {
            this.confirmSelectedDates('baseErrStartDate', period);
        }
        this.checkAwardDateAgainstPopStartDate();
    }
    checkAwardDateAgainstPopStartDate(){
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('startDate') !== null && this.conformedAwardTable.data.length === 0){
            const selectionStartDate = new Date(sessionStorage.getItem('startDate')).getTime();
            this.awardDateValidationCheck(selectionStartDate);
        } else {
            const checkPopStartDate = new Date(sessionStorage.getItem('popStartDate')).getTime()
            this.awardDateValidationCheck(checkPopStartDate)
        }
    }
    awardDateValidationCheck(err){
        this.showAwardDateErrMsg = this.checkAwardDateEntered > err;
    }

    checkBaseEndDate(selectedEndDate, startDate, period) {
        const currentStartDate = new Date(startDate).getTime();
        const currentEndDate = new Date(selectedEndDate).getTime();
        if (currentEndDate <= currentStartDate) {
            this.confirmSelectedDates('baseErrEndDate', period);
        }
    }
    checkAllDates(popDetails) {
        this.popInfoMissing = false;
        popDetails.forEach(date => {
            if (date.startDate === '' || date.endDate === '' || date.awardAmount === 0) {
                this.popInfoMissing = true;
            }
        });
    }
    confirmSelectedDates(errMsg, dateMsg) {
        this.checkDatesDialog = this.dialog.open(ConfirmOptionPeriodDatesComponent, {
            hasBackdrop: true,
            width: '50%',
            data: { data: errMsg }
        });

        this.checkDatesDialog.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            if (result === false) {
                this.setDateValues(errMsg, dateMsg);
                this.isBaseDate = false;
            }
        });
    }
    setDateValues(errMsg, dateMsg) {
        if (dateMsg === 'initialStartDate') {
            this.startDateEntered = '';
        } else if (dateMsg === 'initialBaseStartDate') {
            this.conformedAwardTable.data[0].startDate = new Date(sessionStorage.getItem('startDate'));
        } else {
            this.conformedAwardTable.data.forEach(ii => {
                if (ii.title === dateMsg && (errMsg === 'errEndDate' || errMsg === 'baseErrEndDate')) {
                    ii['endDate'] = '';
                }
                if (ii.title === dateMsg && (errMsg === 'errStartDate' || errMsg === 'startDateLessThanEndDate')) {
                    ii['startDate'] = '';
                }
                if (ii.title === dateMsg && (errMsg === 'baseErr' || errMsg === 'baseErrStartDate')) {
                    ii['startDate'] = '';
                }
            });
        }
        this.checkAllDates(this.conformedAwardTable.data);
    }
    editAwardInfo() {
        this.editAward = !this.editAward
        this.getOriginalAwardByCH();
    }
    openSaveSuccessDialog(releaseQa) {
        this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SaveSuccessComponent, {
            width: '680px',
            data: { data: releaseQa }
        });
        const timeout = 5000;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.dialogRef.close();
        }, timeout);
    }
    onSave(){
        let requestPayload = this.expandTableData1.map(function(res) {
            return {idf: res.idf,startDate: res.popStartDate, endDate: res.popEndDate, awardAmountWithFee: res.amountWithFee}
        })
        this.dataService.modifyPeriods(requestPayload).subscribe(res => {
            if (res.status === ResponseSuccess) {
                this.editAwardInfo()
                this.getConformedAwardByCH()
                this.openSaveSuccessDialog('save-qa')
                return res == requestPayload
            }
        })
    }
    // total sum of Ceiling Amount
    sumConformedAmount() {
        return this.conformedAwardTable.data.reduce((acc, el: any) => acc + el.ceilingAmount, 0);
    }
    // total sum of Currently funded Amount
    sumCurrentlyFundedAmount() {
        return this.conformedAwardTable.data.reduce((acc, el: any) => acc + el.newFunding, 0);
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.chListSubscription) {
            this.chListSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        if (this.originalAwardSubscription) {
            this.originalAwardSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        if (this.conformedAwardSubscription) {
            this.conformedAwardSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    addTitleToPop(list) {
        // PoP has to be manipulated in the FE
        list.forEach((el, index) => {
            el['title'] = (index === 0) ? Constant.base : `${Constant.option} ${index}`;
        });
        return list;
    }

    anyFunction(data) {
        this.orderId = data.orderId;
    }
    checkShipmentPage(data) {
        this.hideModsPage = data;
    }
    // select CH organization from the drop down, to view the original award, modifications, or conformed award
    selectCH(event) {
        this.selectedCH = event.value;
        this.isChAndAwardTypeSelected();
    }
    // select modification types from the drop down, to view the original award, modifications, or conformed award
    selectAward(event) {
        this.selectedAwardType = event.value;
        this.noAwardTypeSelected = true;
        this.isChAndAwardTypeSelected();
    }
    // check if CH and Orginal award type is selected, then only call getOriginalAwards API
    isChAndAwardTypeSelected() {
        if (this.selectedAwardType === 'ORIGINAL' && this.selectedCH) {
            this.getOriginalAwardByCH();
        } else if (this.selectedAwardType === 'CONFORMED' && this.selectedCH) {
            this.getConformedAwardByCH();
        }
    }
    downloadFile(file) {
        if (file) {
            this.dataService.downloadFile({ filePath: file.s3filelocation }, file.nameCode);
        }
    }
}
```

When I select "Modify"
Then the system checks, as applicable, that:
*I did not enter a start date that is prior to the order award date
*I did not enter a date that is prior to the start start of the preceeding period
*I did not enter an end date that is after the award end date
*I did not enter a total amount that is greater than the total award amount
And and error/alert displays to alert me of the validation violation
And I am prompted to correct the data that I entered